# Code for sharing on google plus is causing errors

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, phonegap-plugins, google-plus

I would like to add a google plus share button to my app to share links. My app is built with Javascript, HTML5 and CSS and packaged with phonegap build.

I was using a snippet of code since November, which I got [here](https://developers.google.com/+/web/share/) (under the heading Share Link) and it was working fine in the phonegap build about 2 weeks ago.
However on testing the app again in the last few days it gives me the following error: "Browser isn't supported by google plus".
I tried updating the browser on both of the android phones which I was testing on, however I still get the same error.

Here is the snippet of HTML code (causing the error):

```
<a href="https://plus.google.com/share?url={URL}" onclick="javascript:window.open(this.href,
  '', 'menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,height=600,width=600');return false;"><img
  src="https://www.gstatic.com/images/icons/gplus-64.png" alt="Share on Google+"/></a>
```

So now I am trying out other alternatives to share on google plus from [this](https://developers.google.com/+/web/share/) page.
I'm trying the following basic code in a normal browser (as opposed to packaging with phonegap) however I am having trouble.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Share demo: Basic page</title>
        <link rel="canonical" href="http://www.example.com" />
        <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer>
        <!-- Place this tag in your head or just before your close body tag. -->
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
            <div class="g-plus" data-action="share"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

On running this code in the browser, I press the share button. It brings up a pop up where I am asked to sign in. Once I sign in, the popup closes itself and the content is NOT shared on my google plus account. When looking in the console I see the link has given a 204 response and the following output:

```
XHR finished loading: POST "https://apis.google.com/u/0/se/0/wm/1/_/jserror?script=https%3A%2F%2Fapis.g…com%22%20from%20accessing%20a%20cross-origin%20frame.&line=Not%20available".
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Also I was looking in a phonegap specific way of doing it [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-googleplus) however as far as I can see, it is just a plugin for google plus sing in and not sharing. Any advice would be appreciated. thanks

## Edit

I must mention that the snippet of HTML code causing a problem (mentioned above) is being dynamically generated with string concatenation as follows:

```
var read_story_page_html = '<li>'   
            + '<a href="https://plus.google.com/share?url=' + safe_story_link + '" ' 
            + 'onclick="javascript:window.open(this.href,\'\', \'menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,height=600,width=600\');return false;">'
            + '<span class="google_plus_icon">'
            + '<i class="fa fa-google-plus-square"></i>'
            + '</span>'
            + '<span class="social_sharing_text"> Google+</span>'
            + '</a></li>';
```

This still works in a normal browser (so there is no error in the code). It's just that when bundled up with phonegap, it redirects me to google plus but then says "Your browser isn't supported by google+".

Answer (score 0):

One thing I noticed is that the snippet of HTML code which is causing the error

does not have the {URL} replaced in the href.

It notes on the google developers site under share link to replace {URL} with the page URL you want to share.

Give that a try to see if it gets rid of the error.

Comment: thanks.. I've just edited my question. The snippet of code isn't really the problem. it just seems to be incompatible with phonegap now.